# slickFilter/slickUnfilter was not working properly in Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, react-slick

The slickFilter/slickUnfilter methods are working fine when the page loads/reloads, but when I scroll the site up or down on my iPhone, the methods stop working properly.

I have a list of products in a slick slider that I use to compare each product. I added a new close CTA (X) to remove the product from the list and added a Restore CTA to display all products.

Code:

```
$categoriesWrapper.slick({
                    dots: false,
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    arrows: false,
                    infinite: false,
                    accessibility: 0
                  });
```

To remove product:

```
$removeProduct.once().on('click', function () {
    var slideIndex = $(this).closest($categories).index();
    var displayedSlides = $('.not-disabled', $module).length;
    $categoriesWrapper.find($categories).eq(slideIndex).removeClass('not-disabled');
                
    $categoriesWrapper.slick('slickUnfilter');
    $categoriesWrapper.slick('slickFilter','.not-disabled');
});
```

To restore product:

```
$restoreCta.once().on('click', function () {
    $categories.addClass('not-disabled');
    $categoriesWrapper.slick('slickUnfilter');
});
```

I have checked on all devices and the `slickFilter`/`slickUnfilter` methods are working fine. However, on iPhone, after scrolling the site up or down,
the methods throw the following errors:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.$list.width')
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'b.$slides.removeClass')
```

I have checked the documentation for Slick and there are no known issues with the slickFilter/slickUnfilter methods. I have also debugged my code and I cannot find any errors. I am not sure why I am getting these errors on iPhone after scrolling the site.

I expected the `slickFilter`/`slickUnfilter` methods to work as expected on all devices. I did not expect them to throw errors after scrolling the site on iPhone.